# BOOST_FOREACH broken; is it at all possible to fix?

Tags: c++, boost-foreach

If you use the name of a variable whose name is the same as the name of the loop variable, `BOOST_FOREACH` gets confused:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct Test { };
std::vector<int> test(Test) { return std::vector<int>(); }
Test c;

int main()
{
    BOOST_FOREACH (int c, test(c))
    {
    }
}
```

I understand the cause of the problem, but I'm wondering, is this at all possible to fix?
I can't think of any way around it (that doesn't require virtual functions and such).

Comment: How about naming the loop variable something else?

Comment: @AndreiTita: How do I know when I need to do that? The compiler doesn't always warn me (it only spits out errors/warnings if there is a type mismatch), so the problem is figuring out *when* to rename the variable. In a large piece of code aliasing like this kind of becomes inevitable... you can't always use a different name for everything.

Comment: @Nick: Namespace? No one said the outer variable has to be global... what about when the outer variable is an instance variable, parameter, lambda-captured variable, nested enum member, or something else?

Comment: Err, these are normal name-hiding rules, nothing special about `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Comment: @Mehrdad you'd change it whenever you want to use the variable that's been masked by the loop variable. Even your example did work I wouldn't use it because it looks confusing.

Comment: @Mehrdad If this really is a problem and you need a non-temporary solution to it, just name the loop variables something verifiably unique (by using a namespace for example). It depends on how many times FOREACH is used in the code, but I'm gonna naively assume it's not unfeasible.

Comment: @Xeo: I'm not sure what you mean by "normal", but I certainly don't believe you mean this behavior should be expected -- that's not what C++11 expects when you say `for (int c: test(c))`, and I certainly didn't expect `BOOST_FOREACH` to behave like this. (In fact, I had no idea this would happen until I was playing around with it and a compiler warning popped up in part of my code.)

Comment: @AndreiTita: *"If this really is a problem"* doesn't make sense -- obviously, if I can spot the problem, I can also work around it by renaming the variable. The trouble is not finding out how to work around it, but rather, finding out how to spot this kind of problem (or prevent it completely) in the first place, in a piece of code that's already been written. The only reason I even *noticed* this problem was a random compiler warning I got when writing code I normally wouldn't have -- in other cases the compiler was completely silent about this hidden problem.

Comment: In what cases do you not get a compiler error for this? The only one I've found is when `test` is templated on its argument's type.

Comment: @DavidBrown: Practically always... see, for example, [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3b82K6%248).

Comment: `for (int c: test(c))` is as broken as the analogous `BOOST_FOREACH` construct. In either case compiler won't always warn you about it.